# If an astronaut orbits earth, can both Time Dilation and Gravitational Time Dilation affect it?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, experimental-physics, time, time-dilation

I am very new at all of this stuff and this one thing bugs me very much...

If an astronaut is orbiting earth, it should be experiencing Time a bit faster than those on earth, correct?

Well then because of the speed he is traveling, he will also experience Time a little slower than those on earth.

Correct me if I’m wrong but those should pretty much cancel out, but that sounds completely wrong to me.

If you could answer this question and fix any of my poor logic/ reasoning, that would be awesome :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If an astronaut had stationed in International Space Station for the duration of mission, 17 years, would he be older?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/256335/)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't necessarily cancel out. They can have opposite signs, yes, but it's also possible one effect is much bigger than the other.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as astronaut will be at relatively high speed then it will experience time dilation and also earth gravitational pull is not strong compare to others there will be negligible affect of gravitational time dilation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes on both counts.  There is time dilation due to the orbital velocity (special relativity), and there is also time dilation due to the Earth's gravity field (general relativity).  The signs of each of these are opposite, but the magnitudes can be different, leaving a net effect.  The example I am most familiar with is with GPS (or other GNSS) satellites... here's a good post on that ([Why does GPS depend on relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/why-does-gps-depend-on-relativity)).